# Joining table with multiple-values-field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a vegetation vector layer with vegetation type mapping. I want to join this vector layer with a CSV-file (no geometry) which includes threatened species occurrence.

The vector layer has a `"vegetation class"` field which provides a single vegetation classification for each polygon. The CSV-file has a species list with a `"Class"` field which indicates all the vegetation classes (comma separated) the species is known to occur.

When I create a join between the vector layer and the CSV-table data, there doesn't appear to be anywhere for me to indicate the join field contains multiple values and I, therefore, receive `NULL` results when inspecting the join.

How can I indicate that the value from the target field (`"vegetation class"`), which is a single value, needs to search each row in the join field (`"Class"`) which contains multiple comma separated values?

Comment: You may need to process your CSV to produce a new CSV with a single line for each class with a single value in each class field.  Once you've processed your CSV to a better format, then you can do a one-to-many join.  Multi-value fields are a bad idea for databases in general, and no good for joining.

Answer (score 6):

You can follow different ways to achieve this.

> You can do this with SQL.

**sollution 1**

Go to Database > DB-manager > Virtual Layers > Project Layers

Open the SQL-window and add following code.  Change 'vector_layer' and 'csv_file' to the appropriate layernames:

```
select v."vegetation class", c."species"
from vector_layer v 
join csv_file c 
where c."Class" like '%'||v."vegetation class"||'%'
```

*This code creates a single row for every vegetatian class - species occurence.*

- Check 'load as a new layer'
- Uncheck 'Geometry column'
- Give a layer name
- click load

Now you can define a relation to the newly created table.  Go to project > Properties > Relations.

**sollution 2**

You can create an entire new layer, with everything added in the way you want.

Go to Database > DB-manager > Virtual Layers > Project Layers

Open the SQL-window and add following code. Change 'vector_layer' and 'csv_file' to the appropriate layernames:

```
select v.geometry , v."vegetation class", group_concat(c."species") as species
from vector_layer v 
join csv_file c 
where c."Class" like '%'||v."vegetation_class"||'%'
group by v."vegetation_class"
```

- Check 'load as new layer
- Check 'load as a new layer'
- Check 'Geometry column' and choose `geometry`
- Give a layer name
- click load

[image]

> you can do it with a QGIS-expression

**sollution 3**

add a virtual field to your vector_layer with following expression:

either

```
 aggregate( 
    layer:='csv_file',
    aggregate:= 'concatenate',
    expression:= "species",
    filter:= "Class" like '%' || attribute(@parent,'vegetation class') ||'%',
    concatenator:= ','
    )
```

or

```
 aggregate( 
    layer:='species',
    aggregate:= 'concatenate',
    expression:= "species",
    filter:=  array_contains( string_to_array( "Class" ), attribute(@parent,'vegetation class')),
    concatenator:= ','
    )
```

[image]

Both gives following result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solutions Pieter, appreciate the effort you've gone to explain the process. I'll give each solution a crack to see how they go.  Cheers.

Comment: Had trouble finding the DB-manager because the DB-manager plugin was not checked in the plugin manager.  Once checked, the Database menu appears, DB-manager is under that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do will not work. You cannot join a single value to a comma separated values. What you need to do is create a single csv table that has each value in a distinct row or better create an extra integer column or a code to match the single value to the csv. You might be better of creating a relation which allows you to create 1-M relationships. Can you please share the data. Maybe two rows from each table